# osql.exe can't read special characters

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Hi I am trying to make some update using osql.exe against a sql file which has some special characters.
But the actual update ends up having some funny characters instead of the special characters.
Sample sql is below:

```
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'CA', 3, N'Automàtic')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'CS', 3, N'Automatický')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'DA', 3, N'Automatgear')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'DE', 3, N'Automatik')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'EL', 3, N'Αυτόματο')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'EN', 3, N'Automatic')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'ES', 3, N'Automático')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'FR', 3, N'Automatique')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'HU', 3, N'Automata')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'IT', 3, N'Cambio automatico')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'NL', 3, N'Automatisch')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'PL', 3, N'Automatyczna')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'PT', 3, N'Automático')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'A', N'TR', 3, N'Otomatik')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'B', N'CA', 2, N'2 portes')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'B', N'CS', 2, N'2dveřový')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'B', N'DA', 2, N'2-dørs')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'B', N'DE', 2, N'2-Türen')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'B', N'EL', 2, N'2-πόρτο')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'B', N'EN', 2, N'2-Door')
  INSERT [dbo].[TableName] ([Code], [Culture], [Position], [CodeDescription]) VALUES (N'B', N'ES', 2, N'2-puertas')
```

Comment: Can you show us the SQL you've written, and a sample of the file?

Comment: What is the data type of column `CodeDescription`? Is it by any chance varchar, and therefore can't hold these unicode characters?

Comment: Updated the question with the sample sql. I don't know if I can attach the file here.

Comment: Hmm - perhaps this link might help: http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/10/14/osql-exe-and-unicode-files-how-to-save-your-sql-scripts-with-encoding.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the encoding of the file from UTF-8 to Unicode-Codebase 1200 solved the issue.